# Is it possible for strictly increasing and strictly concave-up functions to cut each other twice or more?

Tags: functions, monotone-functions

Assume that two positive functions are strictly increasing and strictly concave-up, i.e. first and second derivatives are positive. Both functions start from the point $(0,0)$. Then, is it possible for them to cut each other twice or more? If so, can someone please bring a counterexample that shows this?

Comment: I think twice is possible, more than 2 times impossible.

Comment: I think twice is possible, more than 2 times impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $f, g: (0, \infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x^{2}+\sin(x)$ and $g(x) = x^{2}$. They have infinitely many points of intersection.

Comment: Could you sketch why your $f$ is strictly increasing and strictly concave up?

Comment: I used the fact that $f'(x) = 2x+\cos(x)> 0$ and $f''(x) = 2-\sin(x)>0$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @KarthikKannan Thank you very much for this beautiful example. But does this manner happen because of the periodic function $\sin(x)$? I mean when the functions do not contain trigonometric functions, can this behavior happen?

Comment: @KarthikKannan For example, substituting $\sin x$ by $\sinh x$, they do not cross.

Comment: Another question --- can the behavior of an infinite number of intersections occur if one assumes each of $f,g$ is analytic or maybe $C^{\infty}$ and has domain *all reals* ?

Answer (score 1):

Twice;

$f(x) = e^x$

$g(x) = e^{2x} + 0.1$

I don't think $> 2$ is possible but I'm unable to prove it.